# Cannot send post requests in Angular with HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to send a post request to a json file in typescript, Angular with HttpClient. However, I get a 404 not found error, saying it cannot fine the file `results.json`. I find this weird because the get requests all work perfectly fine. Currently I'm using Angular 15.

I tried the following:

```
    let emptyObject = {};

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('/assets/results.json', emptyObject, {headers})
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

The file `results.json` is empty and just looks like this:

`[ ]`

When executing the function it says:

`HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/results.json', ok: false, …}`

I know the file exists and the filepath works because I use the same one for get requests. Is there maybe an option I need to enable or disable? It should be possible right?

Answer (score 2):

You need something like `json-server` or some server to handle the post request. A get request is just like your browser it just gets a resource from a specific URL, a POST request cannot just POST data to some file it has to be handled by a server. For a quick way to set this up for development the npm package `json-server` is really nice if you don't have any experience yet with setting up server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

Some extra documentation about how REST works if you are interested: https://www.codecademy.com/article/what-is-rest